# Why is it faster to first check if a number is a pseudoprime than to divide by all integers up to, but not including, that number?

Tags: number-theory

The Oxford Concise Dictionary of Mathematics defines a pseudoprime as any number $n$ that satisfies the condition $a^n = a \pmod n$ "for all integers $a$". To find a pseudoprime, we have to go about iterating through each integer less than $n$, at least until we get to the point where we can be sure none of the numbers that follow are factors of $n$. Then, if we wish to be sure any number we have is a prime, we still have to divide that number by each of the aforementioned integers.

Wouldn't it be easier to test each n the "grade-school" way?

Edit: I mean, if we do all this stuff on a computer, there can't be that much of a difference between the two tests.

Comment: To check that for example whether $2^n\equiv 2\pmod{n}$ is a cheap calculation. We can similarly check cheaply for any small collection of $a$.

Comment: In grade school I was often tempted to multiply two numbers by repeated addition.  However as the numbers I was assigned to multiply grew larger, I realized that repeated addition was not an efficient use of my time.  It is the same with testing primality.  You might well be able to test most four digit numbers for primality by trial division, with sufficient effort.  But how about a one-thousand digit number?

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, trial division is totally useless already for $100$-digit numbers. And even proving that a number is prime can be done efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we had a number $n$ of size roughly $10^{100}$.  To test for primality by trial division, we would  have to divide by all the primes up to about $10^{50}$ (if the number is in fact prime). According to the Prime Number Theorem there are about $\frac{10^{50}}{\ln\left(10^{50}\right)}\approx 8.7\times10^{47}$ primes to try dividing by.

On the other hand a pseudoprime test with the base $b$ requires calculating the least nonnegative residue of $b^{n-1}\pmod{n}$.  Using a successive squaring algorithm, this only takes about $335$ squarings (for our number in the range of $10^{100}$), multiplications, and modular reduction steps (each of these steps takes a few--about $5$--multiplications and divisions).  So that's about $1700$ multiplication and divisions, compared to $10^{47}$ multiplications and divisions for verifying a prime by trial division.

For a computer, verification of a prime in the range of $10^{100}$,  takes forever (well not quite literally, but longer than the age of the universe); whereas the pseudoprime test can be done in a matter of seconds (maybe less than a second).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean by "residue". I looked in my math dictionary and could not find the word. Do you mean "residue class"?

Comment: Least nonnegative residue is the remainder.  For instance, the least nonnegative residue of $53 \pmod{7}$ is $4$--that is, the remainder in dividing $53$ by $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me point out the falsity of the last statement in the question, claiming that "if we wish to be sure any number we have is a prime, we still have to divide that number by each of the aforementioned integers."

Trial division is *not* the only way to verify a number is prime, and it is not the most efficient way for large integers.  Trial division for prime $n$ requires integer divisions up to $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$.  From a complexity perspective this is an exponential number of operations in terms of the size of input (the bit size of $n$, or $\log_2 n$).

It is known that there exist polynomial-time deterministic algorithms to check primality. See [Primes is in P: A Breakthough for "Everyman"](http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/200305/fea-bornemann.pdf).

For all practical purposes the problem of primality testing can be addressed by a slight variation of the pseudoprime test mentioned in the Question, namely the [strong pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime) test for a sufficient number of relatively prime bases.

This is easily implemented.  If $n$ fails a strong pseudoprime test for any base, it is certainly composite (and such a base is called a "witness" for the compositeness of $n$).

If a probabilistic test (of arbitrary accuracy) is satisfactory, then because a composite number $n$ fails the strong pseudoprime test for at least three-quarters of the bases coprime to $n$ between $1$ and $n$, the chance a composite $n$ would pass $k$ of these tests for bases chosen randomly is (conservatively) less than $2^{-2k}$.  Thus we can control how small we want to make the chance that a "probable prime" is really composite.

This can also be considered a deterministic check, whose sufficiency depends on an Extended Riemann Hypothesis (ERH), which implies the smallest base for which a composite $n$ fails the strong pseudoprime test is at most $2 (\ln n)^2$.  It follows that if ERH is true, then primality can be checked deterministically by no more than that many strong pseudoprime tests, which means the entire test has complexity $O((\ln n)^3)$.  For more details see the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

---

**Added:**  The description of trial division implied in the title of the Question is also overly pessimistic.  If $n$ is a composite natural number, all but one prime factor will be at most $\sqrt n$, so we will try to divide (in the worst case) by whole numbers up to that limit (not "by all integers" less than $n$).

Indeed we don't need to try to divide by every integer up to $\sqrt n$ because if $k$ doesn't divide $n$, neither will any larger multiples of $k$.  In particular, once it is known that $2$ does not divide $n$, we need not check for divisibility by any larger even integers.  Carried to the extreme this means we only need to try dividing $n$ by a set of "trial divisors" $k$ which contains all the primes that do not exceed $\sqrt n$.

Comment: I can recommend as good reading and as basic reference the book [Factorization and Primality Testing](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970400) by David Bressoud (Springer-Verlag, 1989).

Comment: The Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely-Test is very efficient and gives always a correct result.

Comment: What constitutes a "sufficient number of relatively prime bases"?

Comment: I've added some details about how many strong pseudoprime bases we need to test, for either a probabilistic or for a deterministic result.   A careful choice of as few as *seven* bases will reveal the primality or compositeness of any whole number less than $2^{64}$, or in other words, all $18$ digit integers.